# XSLT Not working

Tags: xslt

Hi my XML document and XSLT are not working to produce good HTML... what is going on?

This is basically XML file and I have validated this with the XML Schema but

when I use XSLT file to convert it into HTML file it just generates Courses Catalogue heading
with one paragraph of whole bunch of text.

What kinds of problem Do I have here?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- Generate HTML output -->
  <xsl:output method="html"/>

  <!-- The root template is defined here -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Courses Catalogue</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Courses catalogue</h2>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </body>
</html>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="course">

<p>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="code" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="title" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="year" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="science" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="area" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="subject" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="updated" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="unit" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="description" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="outcomes" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="incompatibility" />

</p>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="code">

Course Code: <span style="color:#C66">
<xsl:value-of select="." /> </span>
<br />

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="title">

Course Title: <span style="color:#000">
<xsl:value-of select="." /> </span>
<br />

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="year">

Student Year: <span style="color:#C66">
<xsl:value-of select="." /> </span>
<br />

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="science">

Science Group: <span style="color:#C66">
<xsl:value-of select="." /> </span>
<br />

   </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="area">

Area: <span style="color:#C66">
<xsl:value-of select="." /> </span>
<br />

  </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="subject">

Course Subject: <span style="color:#C66">
<xsl:value-of select="." /> </span>
<br />

   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="updated">

Page was updated in: <span style="color:#C66">
<xsl:value-of select="." /> </span>
<br />

   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="unit">

Unit: <span style="color:#C66">
<xsl:value-of select="." /> </span>
<br />

   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="description">

Course Description: <span style="color:#C66">
<xsl:value-of select="." /> </span>
<br />

   </xsl:template>  

   <xsl:template match="outcomes">

Course Outcomes: <span style="color:#C66">
<xsl:value-of select="." /> </span>
<br />

   </xsl:template>

  < xsl:template match="incompatibility">

Incompatible courses: <span style="color:#C66">
<xsl:value-of select="." /> </span>
<br />

   </xsl:template>  

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

AND MY XML FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"
             href="courses.xsl"?>

<!--catalogue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="catalogue.xsd"-->

<catalogue xmlns="file://"
       xmlns:xsi="http:/e"
       xsi:schemaLocation="file://">

  <course>

<code>COMP3410</code>
<title> Information Technology in Electronic Commerce </title>
<year>later year</year>
<science>C</science>
<area> Research School of Computer Science </area>
<subject> Computer Science </subject>
<updated>2012-03-13T13:12:00</updated>
<unit>6</unit>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you adjusting the XML namespaces in the question? The changes made to my answer do not match the changes made to your example XML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your problem is that all of the elements are in the `file://Volumes/u1234567/Assignment` namespace, but in your XSLT your templates are matching on elements without a namespace.**

If you look closely at the `<catalogue>` you will see a namespace declaration without a prefix. `<catalogue xmlns="file://Volumes/u1234567/Assignment"` All of the descendant elements inherit that namespace.

**Define that namespace with a prefix in your XSLT and then change the places where you refer to those elements to use that namespace prefix:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:a="file://Volumes/u1234567/Assignment">

    <!-- Generate HTML output -->
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <!-- The root template is defined here -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Courses Catalogue</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h2>Courses catalogue</h2>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a:course">

        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="a:code" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="a:title" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="a:year" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="a:science" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="a:area" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="a:subject" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="a:updated" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="a:unit" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="a:description" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="a:outcomes" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="a:incompatibility" />

        </p>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a:code">

        Course Code:
            <xsl:value-of select="." /> 
        <br />

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a:title">

        Course Title: 
            <xsl:value-of select="." /> 
        <br />

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a:year">

        Student Year: <span style="color:#C66">
            <xsl:value-of select="." /> </span>
        <br />

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a:science">

        Science Group: 
            <xsl:value-of select="." /> 
        <br />

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a:area">

        Area:
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <br />

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a:subject">

        Course Subject: 
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <br />

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a:updated">

        Page was updated in: 
            <xsl:value-of select="." /> 
        <br />

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a:unit">

        Unit: 
            <xsl:value-of select="." /> 
        <br />

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a:description">

        Course Description:
            <xsl:value-of select="." /> 
        <br />

    </xsl:template>  

    <xsl:template match="a:outcomes">

        Course Outcomes: 
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <br />

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a:incompatibility">

    Incompatible courses: 
        <xsl:value-of select="." /> 
    <br />

    </xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```